# Wicket CSS AttributeModifier is not able to change color of text on dynamic click delete link

Tags: jquery, html, css, wicket

I have been working on application which is having wicket framework.In my application there is one page which has multiple rows with multiple delete links for each row.Here ,each row will show data in two text fields:item number,item quantity and one delete link .

Here,when i click on a delete link of a row it should change the css style of text dynamically to red color with line-through.But it is failing to do so.It is showing line-through on the text ,but it is not able to change the color of text to red.

Please find the code below.I am using AttributeModifier to implement the above change.

I also want to implement this change in a alternate way by using separate css file and i do not want to keep the css styling in java but in css file.Is it possible?

```
itemNumb.add(new AttributeModifier("style", true,
new Model<Serializable>("color:red;text-decoration: line-through;text-transform: uppercase;")));
qty.add(new AttributeModifier("style", true,
new Model<Serializable>("text-decoration: line-through;text-align: right;")));
```

Comment: can you reproduce the scenario on jsfiddle?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar.Thnk for taking care of.I am sorry that i can not reproduce.But the above problem is coming in IE br0wsers except IE10.

Comment: @Siddhu, why can't you reproduce it on fiddle? At least post your markup, which generates after link click for one item. And of course you can store css in separate files (look [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/WICKET/Adding+Javascript+or+CSS+using+a+Resource) for example), setting `class` attribute (and not `style`) for each item relating to what you defined in your css-files.

Comment: Also, please use CSS for styling and just append classes. This makes it a lot easier to debug/develop.